# What happens if two threads join together and one of them aborts due to some reason

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

What happens if two threads join together(`thread.join()`) and one of them aborts due to some reason. Will the other continue its operation like normal thread ? or it will also get aborted?

Comment: `thread.join()` merely waits for the other thread to finish, that's it. They are not "joined" in any sense.

Comment: But what if one is waiting other to complete and meanwhile it dies, the other will wait forever or start performing its task

Comment: One waits for the other. The other doesn't know that anything is waiting for it. It's not a "mutual wait". The caller waits, the other one doesn't.

Comment: Got the answer from Malt's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> public final void join()
>                   throws InterruptedException
>
> Waits for this thread to die.

`join()` waits for the thread's death regardless of cause.

It doesn't matter whether the thread dies because it finished running or due to an exception (which is what I assume you mean by "aborted"). It would even work if the thread was never started.